# SBT Native Packager SystemVLoader not generating SystemLoader scripts

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a scala SBT project where I'm using the native packager plugin. I'm bundling as a `JavaServerAppPackaging` and would like to generate scripts for automatically registering the application for startup and shutdown with `rc.d` scripts (Amazon Linux).
In my plugins.sbt:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.2.0-M5")`

In build.sbt

`lazy val server =
  DefProject("some/server", "server")
.settings(serverModuleDeps)
    .settings(ServerSettings.allSettings: _*)
    .settings(CloudFormation.defaultSettings: _*)
    .settings(serverLoading in Universal := Option(ServerLoader.SystemV))
    .settings(serviceAutostart:=true)
    .settings(startRunlevels:=Option("3"))
    .settings(stopRunlevels:=Option("3"))
    .settings(stackRegion := "US_WEST_2")
    .settings(codedeployAWSCredentialsProvider := Option(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("devcredentialsprovider")))
    .dependsOn(sharedJvm)
    .dependsOn(langJVM)
    .enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging, SystemVPlugin)
    .settings(daemonUser:="ec2-user")
    .configure(InBrowserTesting.jvm)`

when I run `sbt stage` I can see a `universal` folder containing a `bin` folder with a sh and a cmd file to start the application. However, there is not code to register/start the application as a system service. Is there any additional configuration required to have the plugin generate scripts for registering the application? What am I missing?

I have a created a basic project to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/MojoJojo/sbt-native-packager-test

Comment: If you want to create a debian package you should run `debian:packageBin` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct. Your sbt command isn't :)

with packageBin ( which IIRC triggers `universal:packageBin` ) generates only a universal zip file. A systemloader is a operating system specific part. That's why it's not included in a universal zip.

Generate a debian or rpm file with

```
debian:packageBin
rpm:packageBin
```

The generated deb or rpm package will have the systemloader files included, because they are in the place a rpm/debian based system would expect them.

Related issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/869